# PHP обратиться к последней ячейке каждой строки таблицы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу решить задачу удаления части данных из html-таблицы.

Лежит сия таблица в переменной $so2. 
Есть регулярка $re2.

Требуется **применить рег. выражение $re2 к последнему элементу td каждой строки tr**.

Не могу сообразить, как мне это сделать. 
Буду очень признательна за подсказку.

P.S. Пример кода, где нужно удалить "Вероника Аполлоновна,", а все остальное оставить:

```
-4314                        </td>
                    <td class="resclass">           Вероника Аполлоновна, +ТЕКСТ, текст, текст-текст, тЛТ-5м, п/текст, д/1/текст/текст, текст/текст, текст/текст          </td>
                </tr>
```

Все остальные ячейки строки (коих 10) не трогаем. **Нужно именно в последней td удалить все, что до первой запятой. + саму запятую** В ячейке перед этой последней - номер телефона, где последние 4 цифры идут подряд, как в примере: -4314

Не получается, хоть убей.

Comment: `preg_match_all('/<td>(.*?)</td></tr>/im', $so2, $matches);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте позиционные проверки. С учётом уточнений из комментариев, вам подойдёт такой вариант:

```
$so2 = '<table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">1</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">3</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">-4314     </td>
        <td class="resclass">    Вероника Аполлоновна, +ТЕКСТ, текст, текст-текст, тЛТ-5м, п/текст, д/1/текст/текст, текст/текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">7</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">8</td>
        <td class="resclass">    Вероника Аполлоновна, +ТЕКСТ, текст, текст-текст, тЛТ-5м, п/текст, д/1/текст/текст, текст/текст</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

$re2 = '~(</td> [^<]* <td[^>]*>) \s* \S+\s\S+, \s* ([^<]* </td> [^<]* </tr>)~x';

echo preg_replace($re2, '$1$2', $so2);
```

Результат:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="7" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">1</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">3</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">-4314     </td>
        <td class="resclass">+ТЕКСТ, текст, текст-текст, тЛТ-5м, п/текст, д/1/текст/текст, текст/текст</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" bgcolor="#D3EDF6" align="center">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">7</td>
        <td width="98%" valign="top">8</td>
        <td class="resclass">+ТЕКСТ, текст, текст-текст, тЛТ-5м, п/текст, д/1/текст/текст, текст/текст</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Эдуард, не получается, к сожалению. Может, я кривой программист (ибо начинающий)? Я дополнила вопрос кодом, для наглядности

Comment: Мне нужно удалить в этом последнем теге <td></td> каждой строки только имя или имя и отчество. Все, что до первой запятой. Мозг сломан уже напрочь. Все оставить, а Веронику Аполлоновну удалить

Comment: Эдуард, проверяю тут: https://regex101.com/r/Ek169n/1/ Ничего не находит регулярка, увы :(

Comment: @Наталья дак вы флаги не корректно выбрали :) Вот тот же код, но с флагами и ссылками [демо](https://regex101.com/r/Ek169n/2)

Comment: О!! ОГРОМНОЕ ВАМ СПАСИБО! А я, и правда, чайник совершенный в php. Тыкаюсь, как слепой котенок.

Comment: @Наталья тут дело не в PHP, а в REGEXP. Эта тема довольно обширная, но если один раз погрузиться в её изучение, то множество вопросов прояснятся. Рекомендую "Регулярные выражения" Джеффри Фридл )